# How to make a finer 3D plot with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

In Python I have longitude, latitude and height information that I want to plot (3D):

`latitudeMeshGrid` (100, 100)

`longitudeMeshGrid` (100, 100)

`heightMeshGrid` (100, 100)

`heightMeshGrid` contains 'NaN's for points that are located outside of a specific (long, lat) region (red points in the figure below):

[image]

If I try plotting this using:

```
ax.plot_surface(longitudeMeshGrid, latitudeMeshGrid, heightMeshGrid, cmap=plt.cm.jet, vmin=np.nanmin(heightMeshGrid), vmax=np.nanmax(heightMeshGrid))
```

I get the following result:

[image]

First of all, the colors at the boundaries seem to be incorrect. Secondly, the plot seems rather "coarse" even though I use a fine grid of data. Is there a possibility to reduce the size of the rectangles?

If I remove the NaN data as follows:

```
longitudeMeshGrid = longitudeMeshGrid[insideBoundary]  
latitudeMeshGrid = latitudeMeshGrid[insideBoundary]
heightMeshGrid = heightMeshGrid[insideBoundary]
```

Then I end up with:

`latitudeMeshGrid` (7023,)

`longitudeMeshGrid` (7023,)

`heightMeshGrid` (7023,)

This I can plot using:

```
ax.plot_trisurf(longitudeMeshGrid, latitudeMeshGrid, heightMeshGrid, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

With the result:

[image]

At least the artifacts at the edges are gone now, but still the plot looks really coarse.

I expect to get something similar as I get in Matlab using:

```
surf(longitudeMeshGrid, latitudeMeshGrid, heightMeshGrid)
```

Which ends up as:

[image]

which doesn't have any artifacts at the edges and looks much finer/smoother.

Comment: In case it helps, I just created a pickle file that includes the following variables: latitudeMeshGrid, longitudeMeshGrid, heightMeshGrid, insideBoundary. I am not sure though how I can share that on stackoverflow.

Comment: To share data, people tend to upload files to google drive, pastebin, etc and then post the link. Since these are regular arrays, you should not use a pickle object (which can hold arbitrary python objects and is hence considered unsafe) but rather use a data format for arrays such as an npy or npz file (created using `np.save` or `np.savez`).

Answer (score 1):

I think the kwargs you are looking for are "rcount" and "ccount" which determine the number of samples in the row and column directions. They both default to 50, which seems to be higher than the results you are getting, but it might be due to unplotted nan values. Digging into the `axes3d.py` file to make a similar plot less coarse I found this documentation in `plot_surface`:

```
rcount, ccount : int
        Maximum number of samples used in each direction.  If the input
        data is larger, it will be downsampled (by slicing) to these
        numbers of points.  Defaults to 50.

        .. versionadded:: 2.0

rstride, cstride : int
    Downsampling stride in each direction.  These arguments are
    mutually exclusive with *rcount* and *ccount*.  If only one of
    *rstride* or *cstride* is set, the other defaults to 10.

    'classic' mode uses a default of ``rstride = cstride = 10`` instead
    of the new default of ``rcount = ccount = 50``.
```

This worked for me, I realize it's a while after your question but I hope it helps anyone running into the same issue in the future.